# In general, can you sign this matrix expression?

Tags: matrices, inequality

To start, I know:

$$ A_{[N\times K]} B_{[K\times N]} > \boldsymbol{0}_{[N \times N]} $$

$$ C_{[K \times 1]} > \boldsymbol{0}_{[K \times 1]} $$

and I want to know the sign of:

$$ D_{[1\times N]}A_{[N\times K]}C_{[K \times 1]} \lessgtr 0 
 \mbox{ ??}$$

What is the minimum I need to know about $B$ and $D$ (and potentially $C$ and $A$) to determine the answer to this? Cases are welcome for illustration.

I can easily solve the $N=K=1$ case, which is that $\mbox{sign}{(DAC)} = \mbox{sign}{(DA)} = \mbox{sign}{(BD)}$ so that it is sufficient to know the sign of $BD$ to determine the sign of $DAC$.

However, is there an generalisation to the full matrix case?

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix or vector being $>0$?

Comment: https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/OT104HighamChapter5.pdf

Comment: In this case, the first two inequalities are a set of $N^2$ and $K$ scalar inequalities respectively. I'm not sure of the correct way to denote that. The final product is a scalar.

Comment: @kennyB Why do you need to include $B$ in the scalar discussion? Isn't it sufficient to know that $C>0$ and the sign of $DA$ to conclude? For the general case you can start by writing $d^TAc = \sum_i d_i \sum_k a_{jk}c_k$. But I doubt you can find some "nice" conditions ...

Comment: B is something that the user of these conditions might know in advance. In the actual problem, these matrices are derivative matrices (Hessians / Jacobians) that come out of an optimization problem.